# Checkout cart after language switcher

Tags: checkout

When on checkout if language switcher is applied it gives 404 error.
If same url is opend in new tab it displays the page.

Comment: are you using custom theme ? is it happening in luma theme as well ?

Comment: The issue is already resolved. The language switcher was modified for multistore and multistoreviews. For switching between storesviews we needed ___store param to be added. While switching between store we don't need it.  
I added a param in phtml to identify urls which are related to same store. This same store url will use same form key and we don't get any error.

Comment: Good to know that :)